# Magento: How to prevent magento subdomain to show in google search index

Tags: seo, magento-1.7, robots.txt, subdirectory, google-index

I have moved my Magento files from sub-domain "/magento" to root folder successfully, and I created and generated the google sitemap from admin catalog > google sitemap, and I added "Disallow: /magento/" to robots.txt file, but I still see "www.mydomain.com/magento/‎" shows when I do seach in google by writing "site:www.mydomain.com"

I tried also to remove robots.txt from root and I went to System > Configuration > General > Design, and at Default Robots I choose "INDEX, FOLLOW"

Still I see "www.mydomain.com/magento/‎" appear in google search

I hope someone can guide me with a solution it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The modified changes will not effect on the spot in the google search results. It will take some hours of time to update all the google servers all around the world and I think this is also based on the traffic to your site and SEO for your site. Wait for sometime to effect the google search results.

Answer (score -1):

Resubmit your domain in Search engines for re-crawling. Fetch as Google Bot will be useful here.